# User still has sudo privileges despite being removed from all groups

Tags: sudo

I have a user, say `userX` on a Centos7 machine. I have removed all the groups from this user and this user is now assigned only to the group `userX`. However, I am still able to use `sudo su` and become `root`.

Sequence of commands:
1. `SSH` in as normal user `sriram`.
2. `sudo` to `userX`: `sudo su - userX`.
3. Become root: `sudo su`. This is allowed without password etc. The ideal behavior would be that `userX` would not be allowed to become root.

Running: `sudo -lU userX`:

```
[sudo] password for sriram:
Matching Defaults entries for userX on this host:
    requiretty, !visiblepw, always_set_home, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS",
    env_keep+="MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE", env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT
    LC_MESSAGES", env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE", env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS
    _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY", secure_path=/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin, timestamp_timeout=0

User userX may run the following commands on this host:
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Where could I be going wrong? What additional information is required from me?

Comment: group status doesn't update until the next login session. This works both ways.

Comment: logged out and logged back in multiple times after making the changes. the issue still remains.

Comment: Did you change the `sudoers` file also?

Comment: I did, but I left this user alone. I added a couple of rules for new groups that allowed them some control over Apache and mounting, unmounting.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo -lU userX`?

Comment: @muru: I think I can now see the problem. The user is allowed to run all commands without a password. How do I resolve that?

Comment: @Sriram start by looking for all `NOPASSWD` entries in your `sudoers` and `suoders.d` files? Are any other files included in your `sudoers`? Are you using sudo with LDAP or something?

Comment: @muru: The `sudoers.d` directory did contain a line allowing `userX` to execute commands with `NOPASSWD`. How do I rectify this? Comment out the line?

Comment: Commenting out should be enough. But you found only one? There are two `NOPASSWD` rules matching this user (note the repeated output - `sudo` prints every matching rule).

Comment: @muru: Nope. That is the only line I found. I ran the `sudo -lU` command again after commenting that line out. I now get that `userX` is no longer allowed to run sudo. Why don't you write this as your answer and I will accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When troubleshooting `sudo` access, `sudo -l` is very useful. `sudo -l` prints your `sudo` privileges, and `sudo -lU user` prints that user's `sudo` privileges (if you have all privileges).

```
$ sudo -l
User muru may run the following commands on laptop:
    (ALL) ALL
```

`sudo` prints a line for each matched rule, specifying the granted privilege, but not the matching criteria.

For example, with the following three rules in three different files:

```
%wheel ALL = (ALL) ALL
muru ALL = (ALL:ALL) ALL
%muru ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

The output could be:

```
# sudo -lU muru
User muru may run the following commands on laptop:
    (ALL) ALL
    (ALL) ALL
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

What you can do is look for rules that grant these privileges, and check how the target user can match them. Each line should correspond to a rule that `sudo` matched with this user, so, if there are three lines, there should be three rules (unless your `sudo` configuration is weird and reads the same file twice or something).